# Windows-Django- can't import own modules-says module not found

Tags: python, django

Both views.py and xyz.py are in app folder.But when I `import xyz.py`
django says `"ModuleNotFound"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `from . import xyz` this should fix that error